# is there a way to make ActiveRecord relations use aliases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a models like

```
class MyTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :other_tables

  scope :my_scope, -> {
    select('t.id')
      .from('my_tables t')
      .where(...stuff)
      .other_complicated_scope
      .etc
  }
end

class OtherTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_table
end
```

Because the scope is using a table alias `t`, when I try to use an inner join like:

`MyTable.joins(:other_table).my_scope`

It breaks because it's trying to do `INNER JOIN other_tables on other_tables.my_table_id = my_tables.id` instead of using the alias: `other_table.my_table_id = t.id`

Is there a way to tell `joins` and other relation methods to use an alias instead of the table name?

Comment: To better understand your question: are you scoping the my_table-model?

Comment: `joins` when called with the name of an assocation doesn't actually give you very much flexibility at all. But it can be called with a string or Arel which lets you perform any query you want.

Comment: If you can give us an example of the schema, models, some example data and the desired output I'm sure we can help you. As is this question is way to vague to be answerable.

Comment: @zaphodbln_, yes.

Comment: @max, I updated the question to hopefully make it a little more clear...  Could you give an example of how I would do this with Arel, returning a relation that can be used to chain other scopes?

Comment: Yeah it's still not very clear. Write the actual SQL you expect it to generate instead of the reader having to cut and paste and make guesswork. Even better is if you can also provide the additional information I asked for so that we actually get an idea of what this is supposed to do. I still don't understand why you think you need to alias the table.

Comment: But basically to alias a table in Arel you do `t = OtherTable.arel_table.alias(:t)`. And to generate a join you do `MyTable.arel_table.joins(OtherTable.arel_table).on( OtherTable.arel_table[:my_table_id].eq(t[:id]))`. https://gist.github.com/ProGM/c6df08da14708dcc28b5ca325df37ceb

Comment: @max, after I have done that, how do I get that to be an AR relation that can have other scopes applied to it?  If I do what you said and call `.to_sql` to see what it is going to generate,  I get "undefined method `connection' for #<Arel::SelectManager...>"

Comment: Ah sorry it should be `join` not `joins` I always get the Arel and AR methos confused.  So given `j = MyTable.arel_table.join(OtherTable.arel_table).on( OtherTable.arel_table[:my_table_id].eq(t[:id]))`. You do `MyTable.joins(j.join_sources)`. Which gives you `MyTable Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "my_tables".* FROM "my_tables" INNER JOIN "other_tables" ON "other_tables"."my_table_id" = "t"."id"`.

Comment: Thanks @max, if you make this an answer I'll accept it because this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not entirely sure, what you are trying to accomplish - but I'd start to rewrite your scope as following:

```
class MyTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :other_tables

  scope :my_scope, -> {
    .where(...stuff)
    .other_complicated_scope
    .etc
  }
end
```

Basically it's about ommitting the "select" in your code.

If you need the IDs (as your example implies), use something like

```
MyTabe.my_scope.pluck(:id)
```

but this is not needed for the joining - just let Rails do this job.

In my attempt I also switched the scoping and joining:

```
MyTable.my_scope.joins(:other_table)
```

and that worked at least for my code.

In the corresponding Rails Guide you find some more information how you can use scopes and conditions: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: The point is, I have extremely complex queries generated that require table aliases to do what needs to be done (subqueries involving the same table), therefore I can't remove the `select` / `from`.

Comment: @patrick sounds like you might need to have both then. one scope that returns the selected id, for when that is important, and one that returns the full table so that you can have access to it for joins